# Changing the CSS class of a child element on parent hover

Tags: html, css

My Html:

```
<div class="parent">
 <span class= "child"></span>
</div>
```

I want to change the CSS of the child span tag when I hover over the parent element and revert the child's CSS on mouseout over parent. How can I do this with CSS & HTML?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`.parent:hover .child{ some props }`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

using the normal pseudo element in css :hover, adding the child element .child to add his style

```
.parent:hover .child{ 
       background-color:red; 
      }
```